# Create Stripe PaymentIntent only when credit card form is submitted

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe Payments in my React app using the `Elements` provider as described in [the doc](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react).

The problem is that the `Elements` provider needs a `clientSecret` from a `PaymentIntent` to be initialised. As I have a low conversion rate on that page, this results in a lot of incomplete `PaymentIntent` and `Customers` being created.

I would like to display the credit card form first, and only create a `PaymentIntent` when the credit card form is being submitted. Do I need a fully custom form or can I still re-use `CardElement` from the Stripe React SDK?

Is there a reason why this could be a bad idea? (besides the fact that Stripe auto payment method detection won't be usable?)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad idea in my opinion. If you only accept card payment and want to defer the PaymentIntent creation until card details is collected, you can reuse you existing CardElement integration. Learn more about the comparison between PaymentElement and CardElement [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-card-element-comparison).

PaymentElement can display multiple payment method types, and that's why it requires the PaymentIntent/SetupIntent's client_secret so that it knows what appropriate payment methods types to display to your customer.